# Does SonarQube 5.5 support several language?

Tags: java, maven, apache-flex, sonarqube

I am working on a project with java 1.7, SonarQube 5.5 and Sonar Scanner 2.6.1.

In the frontend of the application I use Flex. I downloaded the version of the flex 2.2.1 plugin which is compatible with the 5.5 version of Sonar, and I put it in `~\sonarqube-5.5\extensions\plugins\`.

In `sonar-project.properties` I put `sonar.language=flex,java` but she does not work.

When I use just `flex` or just `java` the scan goes correctly. 
But I do not want to scan language by language, rather I want to scan the entire project that contains both language.

This is the trace:

```
INFO: Language is forced to flex,java
INFO: -----------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: -----------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 4.303s
INFO: Final Memory: 45M/304M
INFO: -----------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: You must install a plugin that supports the language 'flex,java'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sonar.language` analysis property has been deprecated since version 4.5 (Sept. 2014), which was a long time ago. There are a number of reasons for this, and you just stubbed your toe on a big one: `sonar.language` only accepts a single value. That's right, using `sonar.language` automatically and immediately turns off multi-language analysis.

You thought you were asking for languages "flex and java" but what you asked for was a single language named "flex,java", which of course doesn't exist. To make this work, remove the parameter altogether, and simply analyze.