# SonarScanner Error : "you must install the plugin that supports the language vb"

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I am running sonar scanner analysis on a vb.net project .But i am getting the error 'you must install the plugin that supports the language vb' .
I have already installed VB .net plugin on server and i have created a quality profile for the same and restarted the sonar qube service too.
In sonar-project properties i'm using "sonar.language = vb" .
Where am i wrong ? Do i need to restart the server?

Answer (score 1):

*vb* is the id used by the VB6 plugin.
The id for VB.Net is *vbnet*.

However, the *sonar.language* property has been deprecated since September 2014 (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451494/does-sonarqube-5-5-support-several-language)). If you don't set it, the scanner will work out plugin to use based on the file extension.